# INSERT INTO and SELECT multiple values in mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I can't get the mysql syntax correct. 
I would like to insert into a table 2 pieces of data, `post_id` and `meta_value` from another table on the same database and todays date, CURDATE()) .

```
INSERT into wp_top_voted
```

(`post_id`, `number_votes`, `todays_date`)

The following:

```
SELECT `post_id`  
FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `meta_key` =  'votes' ORDER BY  `meta_value` DESC   
LIMIT 10
SELECT `meta_value`  
FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `meta_key` =  'votes' ORDER BY  `meta_value` DESC   
LIMIT 10
CURDATE())
```

How do I combine the above into one statment? I tried

```
INSERT into wp_top_voted  
(`post_id`, `number_votes`, `todays_date`)  
values (SELECT `post_id`  
FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `meta_key` =  'votes' ORDER BY  `meta_value` DESC   
LIMIT 10, SELECT `meta_value`  
FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `meta_key` =  'votes' ORDER BY  `meta_value` DESC   
LIMIT 10,   CURDATE())
```

but I'm getting errors.

Comment: Can you add sample data and the expected result please?

Comment: Try to `JOIN` the source tables

Comment: beside the solution suggested by me , you may also want to check for the ' character you used, they seems different to me

Comment: I think when you insert multiple rows into table VALUES part of statement inside the parentheses also need do be separated by parentheses INSERT INTO(colum1, colum2) VALUES((val1, val2, val3), (val4, val5, val6)) etc... in your case instead of val1, val2, val3 you have SELECT statement like VALUES((SELECT statement1), (SELECT statemet 2))..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because of incorrect format of `INSERT INTO TABLE() SELECT`.
Try this:

```
INSERT into wp_top_voted  
(`post_id`, `number_votes`, `todays_date`)  
SELECT `post_id`, `meta_value`, CURDATE() 
FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `meta_key` =  'votes' ORDER BY  `meta_value` DESC   
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a pretty good explanation here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

You need a INSERT INTO SELECT statement

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers;
```

Your specific case should be something like:

```
INSERT into wp_top_voted ('post_id','meta_value','todays_date' ) SELECT 'post_id' ,'meta_value' ,CURDATE()
FROM  'wp_postmeta' WHERE  'meta_key' =  'votes' ORDER BY 'meta_value' DESC   
LIMIT 10
```